# how to move variables between class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
has_many :cals

  has_many :employees , through: :cals
........
end
```

,And the second:

```
 ​class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :cal
  has_one :user , through: :cal
   after_save :ids

 def ids 
   if self.role == 'employee'
     Cal.create(
      user_id: @user.id
      employee_id: self.id
      )
   end
....
end
```

The Question / problem:

When I save or call to function "ids" I get an error because - "class Employee" not recognize the "@user.id ",    how do I fix this?

Comment: replace `@user` with `user`, not need to prepend your methods with `self` btw

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def ids 
  if role == 'employee'
    Cal.create(
      user_id: user.id
      employee_id: id
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclass from an existing class instead of reinventing Rails:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
```

**Note**

The OP has changed the question sometime after this answer was posted. This answer is an answer to the original question.

Comment: +1 I like this answer. OP's code will not even work unless class `ActiveRecord::Baser` exists.

Comment: I do not understand your answer come to be able to expand more please?

Answer (score -1):

You can place `current_user.id` in place of `@user.id`